# How to capture sceenshot of URL request with POST data in PHP

Tags: php, webpage-screenshot

I use PHP script to send POST DATA variables to URL and then URL responses a HTML string.
How can I capture screenshot of HTML string above as it's displayed on browser. It is the best solution if i don't need send 2 POST requests, one for HTML content and one for screenshot.

UPDATE: add more information.
My website crawls html content from other website (by sending POST data to it and then get its response). It is only a string of HTML. Beside, I want to get a screenshot of this response that it's shown on browser as what end-user can see.
All action is done in server-side.

Comment: You cannot capture a screenshot with `php` alone. You'd need some kind of plugin such as `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: I'm very confused. What do you want to do? Could you please specify your question?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to capture through javascript and send it to the server-side.
you can do that in a local code that. check out this following example (HTML2Canvas):
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

Comment: I want to do it in server side, not client side

Comment: There is a script for that. even though I never checked the result -> http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope it help :), you should setup proxy service with node.js or php or more to capture a website :) from url

HTML2Canvas
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

proxy service

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/wiki/Proxies